# SQLite3 generated column does not show up in QSqlRelationalTableModel

Tags: sqlite, qt, pyside6, qsqlrelationaltablemodel

I have a QTableView connected to a QSqlRelationalTableModel. Everything works as expected, however, it seems to be impossible to have a sqlite3 generated column in my model:

```
bhd [INTEGER] GENERATED ALWAYS AS (round(d_mess * 130 / bhd_hoehe)) STORED
```

The above statement is the default way to add a generated column in sqlite3. But it does not appear in my model. When I change the column to a standard integer column, it's there.
It does not matter if the generated column is of type STORED or VIRTUAL or if I omit the GENERATED ALWAYS keyword.

Is this by design? Or a sqlite3 driver problem?

Comment: That's not the problem. All is wired according to the docs. To put it in another way: All ordinary columns show up as expected. When I change a column to be calculated (As addressed above), this column disappears from my model alltogether.

Comment: The command:
`model.record().count` returns 16, when I declare the column in question as `bhd INTEGER`. It returns 15, when I change the ddl for that column to `bhd [INTEGER] GENERATED ALWAYS AS ...`.

Comment: Have the same problem. I think this is a big lack! It is hard to find any related issue on the web while i think dealing with generated columns is quite a common task. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem and find it quite annoying

Answer (score 1):

Views seem not to be affected by this issue. I'm aware it's more a workaround than a solution, but you could create a *dummy* view just with your `foreign key` and the generated field.

For example, I have a simple table `User` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    ID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                      UNIQUE,
    name      TEXT,
    surname   TEXT,
    title      TEXT,
    full_name         GENERATED ALWAYS AS (title || ' ' || surname || ' ' || name) STORED
);
```

As is, no `QSqlRelation` pointing to `User.full_name` will work, as you pointed out. However, I've created a simple view like

```
CREATE VIEW UserFullNameView AS
    SELECT ID,
           full_name
      FROM User;
```

Now the following binding works fine

```
model: QSqlRelationalTableModel
model.setRelation(foreign_field, QSqlRelation('UserFullNameView', 'ID', 'full_name')
```

where `foreign_field` is the index of `User.full_name` that in turn will be mapped as the `UserFullNameView.full_name` field.

Comment: Can you please specify what the `foreign_field` (the first Parameter to `setRelation`) is? Surely I am missing something, but I can only think of the ID column of `User`to be the one to put there. But I want the ID to be displayed and Qt's documentation says: "Note: The table’s primary key may not contain a relation to another table."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Does the edit help?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite it is a bit more difficult to get information about database objects, because it does not have an information_schema. SQLite has the [sqlite_schema](https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html) table which holds raw CREATE statements for all tables/indexes/views/triggers. So the most common way to find all the columns in a table is to use PRAGMA. Unfortunately [PRAGMA table_info()](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) will not display GENERATED columns. But there is PRAGMA **table_xinfo**(), which does display GENERATED columns (and information if they are stored or not).

QSqlTableModel (and QsqlRelationalTableModel) internally rely on the database driver to get the columns of the table. In this case QSQLiteDriverPrivate::getTableInfo in src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp uses PRAGMA table_info instead of table_xinfo to get the columns of the table. I consider this a bug in the implementation of the SQLite driver.

I opened [QTBUG-120382](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120382).